# Bing maps viewer

Tags: bing-maps

Is there a software like Google Earth Pro, but for Bing maps?

I`m interesting in historical satellite images. Google gives such opportunity to get it, their clock icon with time bar and one can see and download images obtained in previous years.

Is this possible for Bing maps?

Comment: Alternative: NASA have World Wind https://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/get-started/

Comment: any specific area are you looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

Bing Maps does not provide historical satellite imagery.

Answer (score 1):

Bing Maps has no such option, but [LandViewer](https://eos.com/landviewer) does. This service has a vast database of satellite images that are updated regularly. All the satellite data is free to use and easy to find.

Here’s a brief guide to free satellite data that can be found on [LandViewer](https://eos.com/landviewer):

- Landsat 4 - archive 1982-1993
- Landsat 5 - archive 1984-2013
- Landsat 7 - archive since 1999
- MODIS - archive since 2012
- Landsat 8 - archive since 2013
- Sentinel-1 - archive since 2014
- Sentinel-2 - archive since 2015

For example, let me show you an image of crop fields in Texas. As you can see per indicators on both sides those images are 5 years apart. You may set any date from 1970 and beyond in the settings bar on the top right and apply any INDEX you need for a deeper investigation.

https://i.imgur.com/erGxat0.png

https://eos.com/landviewer/?lat=31.88426&lng=-95.95493&side=L&z=12&slider-id=LV-TEUw-N19M-MVRQ-XzAy-NjAz-OF8y-MDEz-MTAx-OV8y-MDE2-MDkw-N18w-MV9U-MQ%3D%3D&slider-b=Red,Green,Blue&slider-anti&slider-pansharpening&id=LV-UzJB-X3Rp-bGVf-MjAx-OTAx-Mjdf-MTRT-UUFf-MA%3D%3D&b=Red,Green,Blue&anti